# Is this JavaScript problem possible without loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Currently on a code submission website and it won't let me move forward.

> Using this characters array, print to the console every character which name begins with ‘M’. Don’t use any kind of loop, yet.

> ```
> var filmCharacters = [
>        ['Vito', 'Michael', 'Sonny', 'Freddo'],
>        ['Mia', 'Vincent', 'Jules', 'Butch'],
>        ['Bella', 'Edward', 'Jacob', 'Carlisle'],
>        ['James', 'M', 'Moneypenny', 'Felix']
> ];
> ```

my latest try is

```
for (var i = 0; i < filmCharacters.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < filmCharacters[i].length; j++) {
        if (filmCharacters[i][j].startsWith('M')) {
            console.log(filmCharacters[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `for` loop is a loop. IMO the restriction is ridiculous. I'd ask for a more sane problem.

Comment: Use the Array.map method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: @Niloct That still involves a loop

Comment: Does the array has a fixed size?

Comment: You could use Array.map as stated above or write a recursive function yourself.

Comment: @osekmedia Still involves loop

Comment: You may be over thinking this - they're foreshadowing that you'll be expected to use a loop in the future, which makes me dismiss recursion given that recursion is more advanced than a basic loop. They possibly just want you to literally `console.log('Michael', 'Mia', 'M', 'Moneypenny')` - which is a good exercise so that you understand the expected output.

Comment: @JBallin makes a lot of sense xD

Comment: @JBallin ROFL i feel like im the dumbest man alive right now thank you lol

Answer (score 3):

A `for` loop is a loop.

If you wanted to make the code hard to understand at a glance, I suppose it would technically be possible to do so without any looping mechanism, such as with recursion:

```js
var filmCharacters = [
        ['Vito', 'Michael', 'Sonny', 'Freddo'],
        ['Mia', 'Vincent', 'Jules', 'Butch'],
        ['Bella', 'Edward', 'Jacob', 'Carlisle'],
        ['James', 'M', 'Moneypenny', 'Felix']
];

const checkArr = arr => {
  if (arr.length) {
    checkSubarr(arr[0])
    checkArr(arr.slice(1));
  }
};
const checkSubarr = subarr => {
  if (subarr.length) {
    if (subarr[0].startsWith('M')) {
      console.log(subarr[0]);
    }
    checkSubarr(subarr.slice(1));
  }
};
checkArr(filmCharacters);
```

If even that isn't permitted, I suppose the code be really WET.

```js
var filmCharacters = [
        ['Vito', 'Michael', 'Sonny', 'Freddo'],
        ['Mia', 'Vincent', 'Jules', 'Butch'],
        ['Bella', 'Edward', 'Jacob', 'Carlisle'],
        ['James', 'M', 'Moneypenny', 'Felix']
];
const c = filmCharacters;

const check = str => {
  if (str.startsWith('M')) console.log(str);
};
check(c[0][0]);
check(c[0][1]);
check(c[0][2]);
check(c[0][3]);

check(c[1][0]);
check(c[1][1]);
check(c[1][2]);
check(c[1][3]);

check(c[2][0]);
check(c[2][1]);
check(c[2][2]);
check(c[2][3]);

check(c[3][0]);
check(c[3][1]);
check(c[3][2]);
check(c[3][3]);
```

But this is ridiculous.

```js
var filmCharacters = [
        ['Vito', 'Michael', 'Sonny', 'Freddo'],
        ['Mia', 'Vincent', 'Jules', 'Butch'],
        ['Bella', 'Edward', 'Jacob', 'Carlisle'],
        ['James', 'M', 'Moneypenny', 'Felix']
];

filmCharacters
  .flat()
  .filter(str => str.startsWith('M'))
  .forEach(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the prompt saying to not use a loop "yet", I think they just want you to manually `console.log` the matching characters (for this initial step of the problem).

This is useful so that you know your expected output, which you can use to test against your solution.

```
console.log('Michael', 'Mia', 'M', 'Moneypenny');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's something like this:

```
console.log(filmCharacters[0][1]);
console.log(filmCharacters[1][0]);
console.log(filmCharacters[3][1]);
console.log(filmCharacters[3][2]);
```